# How to set [ENTER/SEARCH/ETC...] key trigger on AutocompleteSupportFragment

Tags: java, android

I have an `AutocompleteSupportFragment` for the `Places` API:

```
<fragment android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/auto_complete"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorWhite"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"/>
```

I have initialized and set everything right but what I can't figure out is how to set a trigger on the keyboard's Search key. I tried this but the key is completely ignoring the code:

```
autocompleteSupportFragment.getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && keyEvent.isTracking() && !keyEvent.isCanceled()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not predict", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Is there something I haven't tried?

Comment: What do you mean by keyboard's Search key? Do you want to trigger the "focus mode"(where we actually can type the address) from custom button?

Comment: No, what I mean is that I'm trying to trigger a function whenever the `KEYCODE_SEARCH` from the `virtual keyboard` is pressed while the autocomplete's EditText has focus (`R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input`)

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3):

"focus mode" = where we actually can type the address.

When we using the embedded fragment, it means we use default placeholder to trigger the "focus mode". If you want to trigger the "focus mode" from custom placeholder then you need to exclude the fragment from the layout.

**a. Using embedded fragment / default placeholder**

```
//GRADLE
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
remove the implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:x.y' 

//XML LAYOUT
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// ACTIVITY
onCreate {
    var autocompleteFragment: AutocompleteSupportFragment? = null
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(applicationContext, "API KEY");
    }

    // Bind the fragment in layout xml
    autocompleteFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment) as? AutocompleteSupportFragment

    // Specify the types of place data to return.
    autocompleteFragment?.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG))

    // Set up a PlaceSelectionListener to handle the response.
    autocompleteFragment?.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(object : PlaceSelectionListener {
        override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {
            val str = "lat: ${place.latLng?.latitude}, long: ${place.latLng?.longitude}"
            Toast.makeText(mAct, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

        override fun onError(status: Status) {
            Toast.makeText(mAct, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
}
```

**b. Using custom placeholder**

```
//GRADLE
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
remove the implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:x.y'

// XML LAYOUT
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home_BTN_autocomplete"
        android:text="show autocomplete widget"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

// ACTIVITY
val AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE = 1212
var mAct: Context? = null
onCreate {
    mAct = this // Needed for onactivityresult hook
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(applicationContext, "API-KEY");
    }
    home_BTN_autocomplete.setOnClickListener {
        val fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG)
        val intent = Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).build(this)
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
}

 onActivityResult {
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            val place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data)
            val str = "lat: ${place.latLng?.latitude}, long: ${place.latLng?.longitude}"
            Toast.makeText(mAct, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to add a function whenever the `KEYCODE_SEARCH` is pressed in the virtual keyboard. On a regular `EditText` the `onKey` method works fine but on the `AutocompleteSupportFragment` the method is completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for ImeOption handler.

If so - here you go

```
autocompleteSupportFragment?.view
                ?.findViewById<EditText>(com.google.android.libraries.places.R.id.places_autocomplete_search_input)
                ?.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                        handleSearch()
                        true
                    } else
                        false
                }
```

It may require some additional efforts, but I think you'll grasp.

Hope it helps.